# Redhat Satellite 5.5.0 Remote Command Setup issue

Tags: redhat, troubleshooting, satellite

I have setup Remote Commands on Redhat Satellite version 5.5.0 and trying to understand how the schedule works.  The Remote Commands are already working on the clients but it appears that when we try to schedule it then it just hangs and only executes the commands when we go on clients and issue rhn_check.

The following are my notes on setting up the commands.  Please let me know if there is anything I am missing here.

1. From the satellite webui alter the channel subscription of the client to enable that tools channel.
2. yum install rhncfg rhncfg-actions rhncfg-client rhncfg-management
3. create the following directory and run file

   /etc/sysconfig/rhn/allowed-actions/script/run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote command execution on Redhat Satellite is pull/poll based by default. The rhn_check command is executed on the interval set at `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/rhnsd`, and it pulls whatever task is scheduled for the client on the Satellite server and locally executes it.

If you want to push commands from the satellite server to the clients on real time basic, you have to install and start the `osa-dispatcher` on the satellite server. And on the client, install and start the `osad` service. On the client, check the `/var/log/osad` log file for any errors, especially SSL certificate related errors and fix those errors before proceeding further.

Full instructions are here -

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Installation_Guide/s1-maintenance-push-clients.html